# Printing out errors in EJS

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have problem with printing errors in EJS because when i use in ejs <%= errors %> I am directed to Error 404 not found. Can someone tell me how it print out?

```
req.checkBody('login', 'Login is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();

  var errors = req.validationErrors();

  if (errors) {
    console.log(errors)
    res.render('index', {
      errors: errors
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

U need to initialize errors first. For example: `res.render('index'),{errors: null});` in the get-method of the index page.